# SSRS personal paper size issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I have a Label with this meassures 
Heigth = 8cm
Width  = 10cm

And need to print in **portrait mode**, the problem is that report builder allways change it to **Landscape mode**

How can I do to force Report builder to accept my meassures without changhing the orientation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A page that has the top edge longer than the left edge is Landscape; those with a longer left edge than top edge are portrait - that's just the way it is by definition.

What you actually want to do is rotate the output of your table so that when you peel off the label, the text on it is oriented as if it is portrait.

Given you are on 2008 R2 you can set the table cell's [WritingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633659(v=sql.105).aspx) property to `Rotate270`. You'll need to resize your cell dimensions to accommodate your text and have your data in columns rather than rows. So your Detail row will be 8cm high and 10cm wide with a number of thin, high columns for your data with the text rotated 270 degrees. Ensure that the report project's `TargetServerVersion` property is set to SQL Server 2008 R2 or it won't support the `Rotate270` option. This should give you the result you are after.

Failing this, you could create a table with a single Detail cell the size of your label, place an image in the cell to fill it and draw the text on that image in the orientation that you want using custom code. [Here is an example](http://www.sqljason.com/2011/01/rotate-text-in-ssrs.html) of how to do this with a code sample.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click the blue background and go to Report Properties, you should see an Orientation selection there. Make sure that's set to Portrait.

If it is already Portrait then the problem is likely to be that the body of your report is too wide for the Paper Size you have selected.

Comment: Nothing. The body size is exactly Width: 10cm and Height 8cm. The same as the body. But Report builder still change automatically to LandScape.